# mysql: find (and display) strings that are not in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a list of strings, and I'd like to see only the ones that are **not** in the database.

For example I have this string: "Conducteur(trice) de bus" that is in the database:

So if I do something like:

```
mysql> select * from job where description = "Conducteur(trice) de bus";
+-------+--------------------------+
| id    | description              |
+-------+--------------------------+
| 14495 | Conducteur(trice) de bus |
+-------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Now if the job "Cinéaste" doesn't exist:

```
mysql> select * from job where description = "Cinéaste";
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

But I want **the exact opposite**, i.e. if the string is here I don't want a result to show up, and if it's not here, I'd like the string to show up.

Here's what I'd like for the same strings explained before:

```
mysql> select * from job [clause i don't know] "Conducteur(trice) de bus";
Empty set (0.00 sec)
mysql> 
mysql> select * from job [clause i don't know] "Cinéaste";
+-------------+
| description |
+-------------+
| Cinéaste    |
+-------------+
mysql>
```

So when the record is found, nothing is shown, and when it's not found, the string I was looking for is shown.

Any idea how I could do such queries with MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Try

```
SELECT 'Cinéaste' AS 'description' FROM `job` WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM `job` WHERE description = 'Cinéaste')
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It was **the** solution. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You should create a table (can be a temporary table) with the list of strings to check, one per row. Let's consider you create a table named `check`, with a column `description` containing the values to be checked. Then you could use this query:

```
SELECT description
FROM check
WHERE description NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT description FROM metier
);
```

Comment: I'd like to do a "like". Something like: `select description from metier_tmp where concat(description,'%') not like (select description from metier);` ... any idea?

Comment: Because in the temporary table I have records like `"Tondeur"` and they should be found in the "good" table like `"Tondeur(se)"`.